# How to update the state for react native component from a text input inside the navigationOptions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to set the searchValue state whenever onChangeText event fires, and I want to make the value of the text input equal to the value of the state. I a trying to do that using the navigation setParam and getParams functions. It does work, but the problem is that the component re render two times with each keystroke. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

import ProductItem from "../components/shop/ProductItem";

const SearchScreen = props => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const products = useSelector(state => state.products.products);
  const promotionProducts = useSelector(
    state => state.products.promotionProducts
  );

  const textValue = props.navigation.getParam("textValue");

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchValue(textValue);
  }, [textValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setParams({ searchValues: searchValue });
  }, [searchValue]);

  console.log(searchValue);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        columnWrapperStyle={styles.row}
        numColumns={3}
        data={products}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={itemData => (
          <ProductItem
            id={itemData.item.id}
            image={itemData.item.mainImage}
            title={itemData.item.title}
            price={itemData.item.price}
            promotion={promotionProducts}
            weightVolumeValue={itemData.item.weightVolumeValue}
            weightVolumeUnit={itemData.item.weightVolumeUnit}
            onSelect={() =>
              selectItemHandler(itemData.item.id, itemData.item.title)
            }
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

SearchScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
  return {
    headerTitle: (
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          placeholder="ابحث عن؟"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          value={navData.navigation.getParam("searchValues")}
          onChangeText={text =>
            navData.navigation.setParams({ textValue: text })
          }
        />
        <Icon name="magnify" size={25} style={styles.searchIcon} />
      </View>
    ),
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#96B1AD"
    },
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navData.navigation.goBack()}>
        <Ionicons
          name="ios-arrow-back"
          size={25}
          color="white"
          style={styles.backIcon}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  searchContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#334B48",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  searchIcon: {
    color: "white",
    padding: 5
  },
  searchInput: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: "right",
    fontFamily: "cairo-regular",
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "white"
  },
  backIcon: {
    paddingLeft: 15,
    marginBottom: 10
  }
});

export default SearchScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the double render because you're rerendering on the update of the searchValue in one useEffect, and updating the navigation prop in the next. 
Try coupling those changes in one useEffect,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchValue(textValue);
    props.navigation.setParams({ searchValues: textValue });
  }, [textValue]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I type it doesn't update the value of the text input until the next render or keystroke. So I added also the searchValue state as a dependency for the useEffect. Now it shows what I type, but also I am getting the double render.